# Dynamics AX 2012 Form Origin

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

"The element does not have an origin value. This element must have a non-null origin value."

I used the Wizard Wizard (Microsoft gets no points for creativity on that name..) to create a new Wizard, and this best practice error was in the system-generated form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for answers, and the only suggestion I found was to restart the AOS.  That wasn't an option in my case, so I thought I would post the solution I came up with.

Export the offending object.  Import it over top of the original.

When it is imported, it will be assigned a non-null origin ID.

Comment: I just wanted to add my two cents here, and say that there does seem to be a bug with the Wizard Wizard, where it doesn't assign an origin GUID to the form it generates.

In my case, I had checked the form in to TFS without the origin GUID, and didn't notice the issue until after it had been rolled out to staging and production. Which means that it now has a different origin GUID in each environment. (Which isn't good...)